# awk script to parse case with information in two fields of file

Tags: awk

I have a `awk` parser that works for all data inputs but one and I am having trouble with it.  The problem is in the below rules steps 1 and 2 come from `$2` (NC_000013.10:g.20763686_20763687delinsA) and steps 3 and 4 come from `$1` (NM_004004.5:c.34_35delGGinsT).

#### Parse Rules:

The header is skipped  and

1. 4 zeros after the NC_  (not always the case) and the digits before the .
2. g. ### (before underscore)  _### (# after the _)
3. letters after the "del" until the “ins”
4. letters after the "ins"

#### Desired output:

```
13     20763686     20763687     GG     T
```

#### Input:

```
Input Variant   Errors  Chromosomal Variant Coding Variant(s)
NM_004004.5:c.34_35delGGinsT        NC_000013.10:g.20763686_20763687delinsA NM_004004.5:c.34_35delinsT  XM_005266354.1:c.34_35delinsT   XM_005266355.1:c.34_35delinsT   XM_005266356.1:c.34_35delinsT
```

#### My attempt:

```
awk 'NR>1 {split($2,a,"[_.>]");b=substr(a[4],1,length(a[4]-1));print a[2]+0,b,b,substr(a[4],length(a[4])),a[5]}' OFS="\t" out_position.txt > out_parse.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in this case, you're better off using a regular expression. This sed one-liner produces the desired output:

```
$ sed -nr 's/.*del([A-Z]+)ins([A-Z]+).*NC_0{4}([0-9]+).*g\.([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).*/\3\t\4\t\5\t\1\t\2/p' file
13      20763686        20763687        GG      T
```

It's not going to win any beauty awards but hopefully it's fairly clear what's going on. The parts in the parentheses are captured and used in the output, separated by tab characters.